How to get an M2 Mac mini printing to a Canon MP990 Printer with Ghostscript/Gutenprint?
I bought a new M2 Mac mini, my first Apple Silicon Mac. The Canon MP990 Scanner still scans fine with VueScan, but printing now fails.
I'd set up the Intel Macs with Gutenprint (I use HomeBrew for as many installs as possible) which worked fine with them and I'm running Ventura (same as my former Macs). I’m avoiding Rosetta because I want to set this up to be as future-proof as possible.
So I installed Gutenprint on the M2 MacMini with Homebrew (fresh M2 install), then tried to set up the printer (USB connection) but had to use the CUPS settings at http://localhost:631/ to add it and assign a "Generic PostScript Printer" driver (System Settings doesn't offer a generic driver). I also installed Ghostscript (a stab in the dark) and generated a "Generic GDI Printer" Ghostscript .ppd file at OpenPrinting (an interesting resource), put it in /Library/Printers/PPDs/ but it was rejected (presumably not for Apple Silicon Macs and/or not 64 bit) when I chose it in the printer setup.
The printer now appears under "Printers & Scanners", the job goes through (a PDF, very slowly) and the printer queue becomes empty. However, nothing gets printed and the printer shows as "idle".
Has anyone managed to get an older Canon printer working? There are a few success stories, but nothing beyond what I’ve tried.
UPDATE: I just spent 3 days on this, having tried every possible solution both suggested here and out there, with no luck. I’m now considering a new laser printer. The scanner still works with VueScan, though…

It’s not likely that you’ll get an older (consumer grade) printer working with newer versions of macOS.

The printer now appears under "Printers & Scanners", the job goes through (a PDF, very slowly) and the printer queue becomes empty. However, nothing gets printed and the printer shows as "idle".

This means you successfully created a GDI printer queue, submitted a job to it, the job was processed but the printer had no idea how to interpret the commands so they were ignored, thus the idle state.
Looking at the Gutenprint page for OS X/macOS it states:

High quality printer drivers for Canon, Epson, Lexmark, dye sublimation, and PCL printers.

While I can’t find official documentation that it is a GDI printer, it is host based given that a generic PCL PPD would function still.  The driver specifically is notated as “Experimental” on the Gutenprint Supported Printers List.

This is an attempt to write a canonical answer to address the continually recurring question “Is my older printer supported under this new macOS version.”  For example:

Canon MP140 Printer driver for Catalina
Does Canon PIXMA MP560 work on Catalina?
Canon LiDE 220 scanner issues under macOS Ventura
Installing old printer drivers (Canon Pixma MX850)

These are all questions/answers of the same theme, just with different printers.

GDI, PDL, and Emulation
Usually, even out of date host based printers can continue to function on supposed unsupported, newer operating systems because the software is still compatible and the printing subsystem hasn’t changed. However in the case of macOS, printers released before Mojave will have to contend with the transition from 32 bit to 64 bit. It’s up to the manufacturer if they’re going to make the port.
Check the Technical Specifications
We’re looking to see what Languages is supported by the printer. In the case of this Canon, this information isn’t listed meaning it’s most likely a host based and/or a GDI printer.
Most consumer grade printers (now, nearly all) are GDI (Graphics Display Interface) or host based printers. They are often also called “Winprinters” as this was a technology developed by Microsoft. They aren’t limited to the Microsoft tech; it could be a proprietary print engine developed by the manufacturer.
Instead of the job being rendered and processed by the printer, it’s done on the host computer instead.  There’s but one reason for this:  cost. With these types of printers, there’s no need for an (expensive) SoC (System on Chip) to handle the processing; that’s done by the computer’s CPU.
PDL or Page Description Language
Commercial printers support PDL. This is a command language embedded in the printer that instructs the printer how to “draw” the image it receives from the computer. Unlike GDI, the job is rendered one the printer instead of on the computer.  Two of the most common languages are HP PCL (Printer Command Language) and Adobe Postscript.  The advantage over host based printers is regardless what happens with the host, the printer has the software to render the job.  The host only need to “know” how to speak the most common printer language on the market.
The caveat here is the printer must support the language.  However, according to the Technical Specifications page, the printer doesn’t “speak” any of these languages including Postscript  You can’t just create a generic Postscript PPD and have it work when the printer doesn’t speak Postscript to begin with.
Emulation
Many of the (older) commercial printers also support emulating other printers.  This means should you lack a driver, you can have the printer emulate a more well known printer like IBM (ProPrinter), Epson, and HP Laserjet; these are some common ones.  Any generic (HP Laserjet, for example) printer driver found in macOS or CUPS will work if your printer supports emulation.  Unfortunately again, most consumer grade printers don’t support this.
What can be done
Unfortunately, not much.  There is the option of setting up an older Mac, Linux or Windows box (if your Mac is Intel based you could do this in a VM) to utilize the compatible drivers/software to render the jobs for printing. In fact, this may get you out of a pinch.
A better solution is to purchase a commercial grade laser printer (toner is much cheaper than ink); something that is typically found in a small office setting.  The initial cost is more, but the long term value you get from continued support is well worth the cost.   For example, I personally use an HP CP2025dn.  Every version of macOS has native drivers for it including Catalina and Ventura. If those happen to go away, there are existing PPDs on OpenPrinting.  I’m not worried about losing support.  I think I spent around $500 about 15 years ago to acquire it and other than consumables and an extra paper tray option, I’ve had zero issues.  It still prints duplex in vivid color like it was new. For the scanning functionality, I got a Fujitsu ScanSnap that’s small enough to fit into a desk drawer.
I wholly recommend this approach.

AFAIK the Canon MP990 is not a GDI printer.

@nohillside, I don’t know if it’s GDI or not, but it’s definitely host based.

The OP claims that it works with Intel Ventura (which also isn't supported according to the Canon page you link to), so I wonder which ghosts we are chasing here.

My guess here is the Intel instance was “brought over” from via Migration Assistant. I think a fresh install would fail

Yes to all the above. Also, it seems Gutenprint is stuck as from 2019 at v5.3.3, so ARM- and 64-bit drivers(?) are probably not listed separately, although my Canon MP990 is on the list as "experimental".

I think you need to install Rosetta 2 to get the driver to work (Yes, I know you have set “Generic PostScript Printer” but I think that you still need Rosetta 2 or to reinstall Homebrew).
Did you setup your Mac mini by cloning or restoring it from and Intel macOS install? Because Homebrew uses a new directory structure (/opt/homebrew/) than Intel Macs (/usr/local) and if you cloned it, chances are it is still using the old Intel directory structure. You need to completely blow away that Intel-based Homebrew and reinstall it for Apple Silicon. That might be the problem.
This is how you can uninstall the Intel version of Homebrew according to this answer on Stack Overflow:
sudo /bin/zsh
# arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"

Also, check out this question and answer thread which explains various methods to get things working again. But I have a sneaking suspicion that your issue is with Intel drivers on an ARM Mac. In that case you need to install Rosetta 2 to get things working. You should be able to install Rosetta 2 from the command line like this:
softwareupdate --install-rosetta


Thanks for the link - checked, and I’ve updated my question - forgot to mention that I’m avoiding Rosetta. Also clarified that my version of Homebrew was installed on the M2 without Rosetta. I think you're right about the ARM processor… and/or it might also be the lack of a 64-bit driver. My setup was a migration, but I now know I should've been more selective and ma considering deleting my account and starting again, although there's another minimal account I want to retain, so some fiddling is ahead.
